Android LocationClient - location updates stop being delivered to BroadcastReceiver
I am requesting location updates using LocationClient.requestLocationUpdates and passing a pending intent to my my broadcast receiver:
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

I am registering this receiver in onCreate of my main Activity. (only once).
The location updates are being delivered every 20-25 seconds but the app stops receiving the updates after a longer period if the device goes to sleep mode and then the device is woken and my app goes to foreground. How and when should I register my broadcast receiver to receive location updates?
